# Migrate password hash from ASP.NET Identity 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Currently, I have password hashes generated using ASP.NET Identity 2.0.

Is it possible to verify these passwords using new ASP.NET Identity 3.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set `PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode` to V2(below code was not tested) :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);
    }
```

also see [How to set PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV3 in ASP.NET 5 Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394898/how-to-set-passwordhashercompatibilitymode-identityv3-in-asp-net-5-identity)

Comment: I have this options enabled. I noticed something weird. When I created account using Identity 3.0 with IdentityV2 CompatibilityMode then it works in application which use Identity 2.0. But when I created account in application which use Identity 2.0 I can't login into this account using application with Identity 3.0 and CompatibilityMode.

Comment: nevermind, my old accounts had empty "NormalizedUserName" field in table. Now it works correctly. Thanks

Comment: Please note that `PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2` will **also store the password using the old (and insecure) format**! The default password hasher for Identity 3 **already** has support for validating the old IdentityV2 formatted password, without any need of changing the compatibility mode. You should keep the compatibility mode to V3. The only good reason to modify the compatibility mode to V2 is for applications that use **both** the old and the new identity system at the same time.