# Does .NET 5 Identity CreateAsync() use sha512 for hashing and salting

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I am currently using the inbuilt .NET 5 Identity CreateAsync() to create new user accounts. This is meant to take their passwords, hash them and then salt them. Does .NET 5 CreateAsync() method use SHA1, SHA256, or SHA512 and does it salt them?

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b56bb17db3ae73ce5a8664a2023a9b9af89499dd/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs

Comment: .NET 5 is already out of support. You should be migrating to .NET 6, the Long-Term-Support version that will be supported until 2024. .NET 5 was a "current", ie single-year version. The lifecycle was announces years ago, when .NET 3 was released

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [PasswordHasher source code for .NET 5.0.17](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.17/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L29):

```
     /* =======================
     * HASHED PASSWORD FORMATS
     * =======================
     *
     * Version 2:
     * PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations.
     * (See also: SDL crypto guidelines v5.1, Part III)
     * Format: { 0x00, salt, subkey }
     *
     * Version 3:
     * PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 10000 iterations.
     * Format: { 0x01, prf (UInt32), iter count (UInt32), salt length (UInt32), salt, subkey }
     * (All UInt32s are stored big-endian.)
     */
```

> **NOTE:** [.NET 5 is no longer under support](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) as of May 10, 2022, so there will be no security patches. You should upgrade to .NET 6+ ASAP.

Comment: Thank you. so version 2 uses sha1, but version 3 uses sha256. How do I ensure that I am on version 3 and not on 2?

Comment: See [How to set PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV3 in ASP.NET 5 Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394898/how-to-set-passwordhashercompatibilitymode-identityv3-in-asp-net-5-identity)

Comment: @GolfBravo If you look at the top of the code file that was linked to, it shows how it chooses. Remember, when you're dealing with open source code, you can just go look to satisfy your curiousity.

Comment: Many thanks, Just saw in NightOwl888 answer that if the password hash starts with the char letter "A" 0x01, then it's version 3, which is SHA256, and 0x00 is version 2, SHA1. The current passwords are showing the start letter as A.