# Authentication Issue: .NET Core 6 and .NET Framework 4.8 Applications Sharing Common AspNet Identity Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0, .net-4.8

I have two applications: one targeting .NET Core 6, and the other targeting .NET Framework 4.8. Both applications share a common SQL database with ASP.NET Identity tables.

However, the application using .NET 4.8 is unable to authenticate even with the correct username and password. Both applications have the latest version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core`, which is 8.0.0.

```
// Package reference for .NET Framework 4.8.
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" version="8.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />

// .NET Core 6.
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="8.0.0" />
```

Could someone please tell me what the issue might be in this case?

Comment: What do you mean `unable to authenticate` ? What error do you get?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from same client machine to same server machine?  I would check the log files using SQL Server Management Studio.  The log files are in the explorer under Management.  Check login Group/User when working and not working in the log file.  The Group/User should be the same for both 4.8 and 6.0.  If you are not seeing the connection for 4.8 than you probably have a TLS issue (only guessing).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Unable to authenticate` means it always gives me `false` result while checking password even with correct password - `await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Password)`

Answer (score 2):

The .NET Core 6 application and the application with .NET Framework 4.8, both with identity use two completely different hashing algorithms. So even though you register from one application and try to log in from the other, the passwords won't match.

See this article: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-asp-net-core-identity-passwordhasher/

[Extracted text from blog]

```
- ASP.NET Identity Version 2: PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations
- ASP.NET Core Identity Version 3: PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 10000 iterations
```

Using `PasswordHasherOptions` class you can override and specify which version of password hashing you would like to use.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordhashercompatibilitymode?view=aspnetcore-](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordhashercompatibilitymode?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

```
services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2;
    });

    services.AddScoped(typeof(IPasswordHasher<>), typeof(PasswordHasher<>));
```

P.S. I would assume that you would have to choose an application. If so I would go with the .Net Core 6 application, as its hashing algorithm adheres to modern security standards.

Comment: Yes it worked but is there any way to user `IdentityV3` into .NET Framework 4.8

Comment: Can you check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394898/how-to-set-passwordhashercompatibilitymode-identityv3-in-asp-net-5-identity